# Bootstrap 5 collapse show/hide not working when invoked with JS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am attempting to use javascript to show or hide a collapsable element but not both.
(that is to say i dont want toggle to be enabled)

according to the documentation
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/#via-javascript

i can do something like this to trigger toggling between shown and hidden

```
    var myCollapse = document.getElementById('myCollapse')
var bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(myCollapse, {
  toggle: true
})
```

of course if i change toggle to false it stops it from doing anything - as expected.
however it also says i can use the show and hide properties on an object passed as the second array to enable/disable these behaviors

like so

```
    var myCollapse = document.getElementById('myCollapse')
var bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(myCollapse, {
  toggle: false,
  show: true,
  hide: false
})
```

but if i try to use these options only toggle works

I looked at the BS js and found that it does check the status of toggle

```
if (_this._config.toggle) {
    _this.toggle();
  }
```

however there is no equivalent for show and hide which suggests to me that the show and hide options of the bootstrap.Collapse() object do nothing.

Am I correct in my belief that the show and hide options dont work when using bootstrap.Collapse()?

If no what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`toggle` is both a [config option](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/#options), and a [method](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/#methods) `.toggle()`

`show()` and `hide()` are [methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/#methods), *not* config options.

Therefore, using `show` and `hide` and as config options does nothing...

```
var bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(myCollapse, {
  toggle: false,
  show: true, //useless
  hide: false //useless
})
```

However, `show` and `hide` work as methods...

```
bsCollapse.show()
```

***or***

```
bsCollapse.hide()
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/DB7YTGOPl9)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to toggle the collaspe :

```
new bootstrap.Collapse(myCollapse, {
  toggle: true
});
```

**- toggle option must be true.**

=> Toggles the collapsible element on invocation of the instance constructor.

**- no nead to point a variable to the collapse instance.**

if you want to show or hide the collapse :

```
var bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(myCollapse, {
  toggle: false
})

bsCollapse.show();

or

bsCollapse.hide();
```

**- toggle option must be false.**